# How to get/set session_id() or should it be generated automatically?

Tags: php, session, unique

I have some basic session handling in my application. In each page I check if the user is logged in. If they are then they're already identified by `$_SESSION['user_id']`, and their login/logout is recorded in a MySQL table.

I would also like to record visits by guests (not logged in) based on a unique id. 
I had assumed that once `session_start()` is called that an internal `session_id` is automatically generated and that calling `session_id()` I could retrieve this. But this just gives an "undefined variable" error, so I guess I have to set it manually..? If so then what's the best way so that it will be a unique ID, or what is the usual method?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use sessions and session id's in PHP:

1 - Auto generate the session ID and get it:

```
session_start();
$id = session_id();
```

2 - Set the session ID manually and then start it:

```
session_id( 'mySessionId' );
session_start();
```

If you intend to **set** the session ID, you must set it **before** calling session_start();
If you intend to generate a random session_id (or continue one already started in a previous page request) and then **get** that id for use elsewhere, you must call `session_start()` **before** attempting to use `session_id()` to retrieve the session ID.

Comment: Sorry, deleted last comment. I now see my error! Thanks for this info.

Comment: Not a problem :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see it works for me (session is started silently) : http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/f6b6b.php

You forgot to start your session, probably

Comment: Yeah I just tried it on a test page and it works as you suggest.  But in my app I'm using a class for my sessions, and only calling session_start() once from within the constructor. So the problem seems to be only with getting/setting session_id() in a class method, but no problem setting/getting vars in the $_SESSION array.. Thanks though, I didn't know about it starting silently.

Comment: @grainne: nonono, you didn't get me. It's my sandbox's behavior - session is started automatically, so you can't see it inside "show code", you have to `session_start()` first and after that, you can use `session_id()`

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I get what you're saying now, first time I thought it was just some pasted code. Not sure what was happening for me then :/  I'll have to do some proper testing of all this later...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may be a little bit strange, but when I need unique ID I use uniqid()

Comment: Didn't know about this :)  I think what I'll do then is just use something like $_SESSION['guest_id'] with uniquid, as session_id() isn't working for whatever reason!